# Error when opening shortcut QtCreator

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, qt

I've recently installed QtCreator 5.7. on my Lubuntu 16.04 from official website and created a shortcut using this command:

```
ln -s ~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator ~/Desktop/qtcreator
```

But when I running created shortcut QtCreator IDE opens and I get next error:

```
Could not open /home/alexlubuntu/Desktop/qtcreator for reading. 
Either the file does not exist or you do not have the permissions to open it.
```

Any idea how to fix this? I appriciate any help.

Comment: The error message is telling you what the problem is. Does `/home/alexlubuntu/Desktop/qtcreator` exist? do you have permissions to open/run it? Also `qtcreator` is located in `/usr/bin` by default.

Comment: Already fixed the path was wrong